# iptables command not found in docker-compose container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, iptables

We have the docker-compose file

```
version: '3'
services:
    prometheus-server:
        image: prom/prometheus
        ports:
            - 9090:9090
        volumes:
            - ./prometheus/prometheus.yml:/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml

    grafana-ui:
        privileged: true
        image: grafana/grafana-oss:latest
        ports:
            - 3000:3000
        environment:
            - GF_SECURITY_ADMIN_PASSWORD=secret
        links:
            - prometheus-server:prometheus
        cap_add:
            - NET_RAW
            - NET_ADMIN
```

However, the `/bin/sh: iptables: not found` when we try to run `iptables -nvL -t nat` through `docker exec -it <grafana-ui container id> /bin/sh`. Is there anything am I missing? How to run `iptables` in the docker container?

Per this question [Installing iptables in docker container based on alpinelinux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41706983/installing-iptables-in-docker-container-based-on-alpinelinux), the parameters `--cap-add=NET_ADMIN` and `--cap-add=NET_RAW` is added, however, I failed to run `iptables` either.

Comment: Generally you don't: each container has its own network interface that's fully managed by Docker, and Linux privileges further prevent you from doing it.  The workflow you describe would also make a temporary change that will be lost when you recreate the container.  Why are you trying to run `iptables` in a debugging shell?

Comment: Actually, per this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41707573/how-does-docker-embedded-dns-resolver-work/50730336#50730336), I want to know how embedded DNS server work in docker @DavidMaze

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> /bin/sh: iptables: not found

This means the `grafana/grafana-oss:latest` default doesn't include the `iptables` command.

You could install it with `apk add --no-cache iptables ip6tables`, see [Running (and debugging) iptables inside a Docker container](https://hangarau.space/running-and-debugging-iptables-inside-a-docker-container/).

A quick experiment as next:

```
nxa13855@shlava:~$ docker run --entrypoint /bin/bash -idt --cap-add=NET_ADMIN --cap-add=NET_RAW grafana/grafana-oss:latest
21296933a1d59c45c68c8ab1120b4324b717aea8d220ca070c2c8f21c449e6a5
nxa13855@shlava:~$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                        COMMAND                  CREATED         STATUS         PORTS                    NAMES
21296933a1d5   grafana/grafana-oss:latest   "/bin/bash"              8 seconds ago   Up 7 seconds   3000/tcp                 awesome_villani
nxa13855@shlava:~$ docker exec -uroot -it 21296933a1d5 /bin/bash
bash-5.1# apk add --no-cache iptables ip6tables
fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.14/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.14/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
(1/4) Installing libmnl (1.0.4-r1)
(2/4) Installing libnftnl-libs (1.2.0-r0)
(3/4) Installing iptables (1.8.7-r1)
(4/4) Installing ip6tables (1.8.7-r1)
Executing busybox-1.33.1-r6.trigger
Executing glibc-bin-2.30-r0.trigger
/usr/glibc-compat/sbin/ldconfig: /usr/glibc-compat/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 is not a symbolic link

OK: 29 MiB in 38 packages
bash-5.1# iptables -nvL -t nat
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
bash-5.1#
```

For you, you may need to write you owner dockerfile extends from `grafana/grafana-oss:latest`, in that dockefile, add `apk add --no-cache iptables ip6tables` to make your image default has the `iptables` command.

If just for debug, you could directly exec into that container to install command just like what I did above, but remember add `-uroot` when `exec` as that image default not use `root`.